# NUnit v 3.5 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 v 4.6.01055 Unit tests fail when running them but passes at Debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit

I've struggled for a while with **NUnit** framework (recently transitioned from the flawless TestNG and Java). I'm trying to achieve one thing: initialize some piece of code **only once** before all my tests run, then initialize some other piece of code **every time** my tests start. For the first task I'm using `[OneTimeSetUp]` attribute and for the second `[SetUp]`. Seems like everything should work perfect, but at run time my `[SetUp]` method fails due to the `NullReferenceException` to the object, that is suppose to be created in `[OneTimeSetUp]` attribute method. Interesting thing is that in Debug mode all goes well, even without break points. Tests start normally. Please see my code snippet below:

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
 public void taskBeforeAllTests()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("PathToChromeExecutable");
            driver.navigate().GoToURL("http://www.google.com");
        }
```

then I would like to open new tab at the opened Chrome browser:

```
[SetUp]
public void taskBeforeEachTests()
{
            IJavaScriptExecutor jse = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);
            jse.ExecuteScript("window.open();");
}
```

So the problem is whenever I call `IJavaScriptExecutor jse = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver)` line of code, the test fails at driver object with **NullReferenceException**. My question to VS experts and whoever faced this situation before. Is there any configuration needs to be made at VS settings/options? From what I seeing, my piece of code works as expected in Debug mode, so may be some adjustments needs to be made in Visual Studio itself? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "flawless" but your one time setup initializes a local variable "driver", which immediately goes out of scope. Your setup is using another "driver", presumably a member variable, which is not initialized.

Comment: So how to explain that Debug mode sees that "local" variable, whereas run rime doesn't recognize it?

Comment: Hard to say without more code, but there is no doubt that the "driver" in your one-time setup is not the same as the one in your setup - at least assuming the code you posted is identical to the code you are running.

Comment: Logically thinking, YES, you are right. That simply mean that the driver object in OneTimeSetUp is not the same in SetUp. However, the initial question was how does the Debug mode sees the first object and uses it for further code execution? I might need to research differences between Debug code execution and Run in Visual Studio IDE.